# What is the book where an AI-controlled satellite weapon is destroying energy sources on earth?

Tags: story-identification, weapon, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to find the title and author of a book I read some years ago.

The only plot point I can remember is that an AI-controlled satellite weapon is destroying energy sources on earth - right down to those larger than a camp-fire.

I have searched the web but with no success.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like [Souls in the Great Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Souls_in_the_Great_Machine) by Sean McMullen could fit the bill - does it feature man-powered computers in Australia?

Answer (score 2):

John Ringo's [The Council Wars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Council_Wars) also has a similar premise.

An AI space based entity, called Mother, sets the limits on energy densities and siphons of any which falls above the limits. The series is set in the post apocalyptic world.

Comment: The Council Wars is a good series but its set in more of a fantasy world rather than traditional post apocalypse